# Generate dynamic CZML data using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, dynamic-data, cesiumjs, czml

[Cesium](http://cesiumjs.org) has the ability to render dynamic data that originates from a czml file. They have an [example](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=CZML.html&label=Showcases) on their website showing how use the czml data on the client-side.

I'd like to generate czml data dynamically on the server-side using nodejs. Are there any pointers or examples on how that can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an official [czml-writer for C# and Java](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/czml-writer), and a 3rd-party [czml writer for Python](https://github.com/cleder/czml), but I'm not aware of any yet available for NodeJS.

It seems like one could easily output CZML from NodeJS just by calling `JSON.stringify` on an array of [CZML packets](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/czml-writer/wiki/Packet) (specially-formatted JavaScript objects).  For dates and intervals, one could even import Cesium (or Cesium Core) into NodeJS for access to `JulianDate` and related time interval classes, to store in the appropriate fields.

You'll need to make sure the first element in the array is the `"id" : "document"` packet (as shown in the [guide](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/czml-writer/wiki/Packet)) with the settings for the rest of the CZML data, and that each subsequent packet provides a unique `id` of its own.  After that just push some entity description packets into the array, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks emac, that's extremely helpful. I've followed your advice and have almost put together a working solution. There's something I haven't quite wired up correctly. Would you mind having a look at my post over here? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cesium-dev/lhzR6eUEAnM

Answer (score 1):

For earth orbiting objects, you can use the [czml-writer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/czml-writer) npm package. Here's some basic usage:

```
var czml = require("czml-writer");

var orbit = new czml.orbit.fromParams({
    apogee: 426.9, // km
    perigee: 416.2, // km
    inclination: 51.65, // deg
    rightAscension: 304.1, // deg
    argumentOfPeriapsis: 117.8 // deg 
});
var output = orbit.czml();





var czml = require("czml-writer");

var tle = 'NOAA 14\n' +
    '1 23455U 94089A   97320.90946019  .00000140  00000-0  10191-3 0  2621\n' +
    '2 23455  99.0090 272.6745 0008546 223.1686 136.8816 14.11711747148495';
var orbit = new czml.orbit.fromTle(tle);
var output = orbit.czml();
```